# Improve ARIMAX model, compared to arima model

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, prediction

I am trying to model an ARIMAX model on my time series.

```
> dput(tsOenb)
structure(c(1.0227039, -5.0683144, 0.6657713, 3.3161374, -2.1586704, 
-0.7833623, -0.2203209, 2.416144, -1.7625406, -0.1565037, -7.9803936, 
9.4594715, -4.8104584, 8.4827107, -6.1895262, 1.4288595, 1.4896459, 
-0.4198522, -5.1583964, 5.2502294, 1.0567102, -1.0923342, -1.5852298, 
0.6061936, -0.3752335, 2.5008664, -1.3999729, 2.2802166, -2.1468756, 
-1.4890328, -0.79254376, 3.21804705, -0.94407886, -0.27802316, 
-0.20753079, -1.12610048, 2.0883735, -0.7424854, 0.44203729, 
-1.48905938, 1.39644424, -3.8917377, 11.25665848, -9.22884035, 
3.26856762, -0.00179541, -2.39664325, 4.00455574, -5.60891295, 
4.6556348, -4.40536951, 6.64234497, -7.34787319, 7.56303006, 
-8.23083674, 4.43247855, 1.31090412, 1.0227039, -5.0683144), .Tsp = c(2000.25, 
2014.75, 4), class = "ts")
> quaterlyDummies <-  seq(ISOdate(2000,4,1), ISOdate(2014,12,31), by = "quarter") # or "3 months"
> month <- month(quaterlyDummies)
> xreg <- model.matrix(~as.factor(month))[1:59]
> fit <- auto.arima(tsOenb, xreg=xreg) 
> accuracy(fit)
                       ME     RMSE      MAE      MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 7.215274e-17 4.216134 3.144967 45.39733 146.9616 0.8467543 -0.7332704
> plot(tsOenb)
> lines(fitted(fit),col=2)
> 
> fit1 <- auto.arima(tsOenb) 
> accuracy(fit1)
                    ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.0707266 2.306156 1.739384 -3468.434 3627.246 0.4683134 0.003527999
> plot(tsOenb)
> lines(fitted(fit1),col=2)
```

Here is the output of my `arima model`:

[image]

Here is a plot of my `ARIMAX model`:

[image]

Any suggestions why my `Arimax model` is so bad? Were my dummy variables created wrongly?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What dummies did you add ? Were there 3 dummies for the quarterly effect ? What was the model form of the arima coefficients. ? What were the estimated model parameters ? What did the error process look like in terms of a residual plot against time and an acf plot ? For me to find out what you or your software did wrong (or right ! ) I would like to have some details.

Comment: Your data has outliers, arima models without outlier correction for a data like yours is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `xreg` matrix and you should spot the problem. The following code does what you are trying to do more simply.

```
library(forecast)
xreg <- seasonaldummies(ts0enb)
fit <- auto.arima(ts0enb, xreg=xreg)
accuracy(fit)
```

It does not work as well as the standard ARIMA model because the seasonality is not strong (or perhaps it changes so much over the time period that it is difficult to model).

Comment: Thx for your reply! How can I make a forecast using the ARIMAX model? When I try, `fcst <- forecast(fit, h=20)` I get the error: `Error in forecast.Arima(fit, h = 20) : No regressors provided`. I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: I just compared the `arimax` and the `arima` plot and their accuracy measures. It seems to me that there are no large improvements using an ARIMAX model. What might be the reasons for this and how could the arimax model itself be improved without curvefitting it. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Kare, to be able to forecast with ARIMAX you need to supply the forecasts of the external regressors. If you do not, you get the error message.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thx for your reply! So basically I create a simple arima model and supply this? I do not get how you exactly mean, to supply the forecasts with external regressors. Please post an example!

Comment: You have $y_t=\mathbf{x_t \beta}+\varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ follows ARMA($p$,$q$). Actually, you need not pay attention to the error structure this time. The point is, to be able to obtain a forecast for $y_{t+1}$ you need to have $\mathbf{x_{t+1}}$; you cannot get away without supplying this value.

Comment: @RichardHardy I guess I understand what you mean by forecasting. However, should I den just make a regression using the ARMA model? What I do not get is, how to implement this in R?

Comment: @Kare. Try reading my textbook on the subject: http://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1